# How to reliably hide elements when using JQueryUI Sortable?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a collection of DIVs with a lot of content (titles and textareas) in them.  I want them to be draggable/sortable with JQueryUI's sortable() system.  But there's so much content in each DIV, I want to hide unneeded content when the user starts dragging, and restore the content when they stop.

It works merely *okay* when dragging items near the top of the list.  But when there's more content than what fits on the screen, dragging the lower elements up the list is flaky and definitely a bad user experience.

My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.handle').mousedown(function() { $('.stuff-to-hide').hide(); });

    $("#SortParent").sortable({
        handle: '.handle',
        items: '.sort-child',       
        start: function(event, ui) {    
            $('.stuff-to-hide').hide();
            $('.sort-child').addClass('diff-height');
        },
        helper: function() { return '<p>MY DRAGGING BAR</p>'; },
        forceHelperHeight: true,
        stop: function() {
            $('.stuff-to-hide').show();
            $('.sort-child').removeClass('diff-height');
        }
    });
});
```

I have a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FzUZg/8/ that demonstrates the problem.  Make your window small enough so that some of the DIVs are off the screen, scroll to the bottom one, then try dragging it up.

How do I make the experience easier and more reliable?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `cursorAt` option, it seems to help quite a bit.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FzUZg/11/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.handle').mousedown(function() { $('.stuff-to-hide').hide(); });

    $("#SortParent").sortable({
        cursorAt: {top:25, left:15},  //Important bit
        handle: '.handle',
        items: '.sort-child', 
        start: function(event, ui) {    
            $('.stuff-to-hide').hide();
            $('.sort-child').addClass('diff-height');
        },
        helper: function() { return '<p>MY DRAGGING BAR</p>'; },
        forceHelperHeight: true,
        stop: function() {
            $('.stuff-to-hide').show();
            $('.sort-child').removeClass('diff-height');
        }
    });
});
```

Or you could consider using some sort of sortable accordion like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pLmRx/)**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#accordion")
         .accordion({
         active: true,
         header: "> div > h3",
         collapsible: true
     })
         .sortable({
         forceHelperSize: true,
         cursorAt: {
             top: 5
         },
         tolerance: 'pointer',
         axis: "y",
         handle: "h3",
         placeholder: "place",
         start: function () {
             var active = $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active");
             $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", false);
         },
         stop: function (event, ui) {
             // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
             // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
             ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
         }
     });
 });
```